# Styling specific element of a div in css

Tags: css, html

I have a div called mycontent. In this div there is a h2 element. This element inherits global properties, but I would like to change its color only within the mycontent div. I would prefer not to add new class because I would like to operate only within the css.
I have something like that:

```
#mycontent {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
left: 10px;


}

#mycontent h2 {
    color: #fff;

}
```

Comment: You must have more specific css elsewhere, or have some duplicate level css with differing values later otherwise, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point being? I mean, you already have the right CSS to achieve what you're asking. The #mycontent h2 {} selector you wrote is right :)

Comment: If it's not working, it means you have other css selectors that override that and take priority. The declaration "as you wrote it" works just fine. Try with a new html page and a simply css with just those declarations, and you'll see it works.